# Envelope document list being reset after

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the API to create an envelope then I upload documents to that envelope. All is good except when I call the Sender View after that it resets my envelope count to 1 and only has the first document I uploaded. Is this a session thing or what. Why would it reset the envelope documents ?

Comment: I'm now seeing the error "The user is not the owner of the lock. The envelope is locked by another user or in another application "

Comment: Any idea as to why this is happening in the DEMO environment ?

Comment: Can you post your request / responses of creating the envelope / uploading the additional documents?

Comment: As Andrew mentions please post your request/responses from DocuSign, pretty hard to diagnose without that.  And are you positive that the request to add the docs has completed by the time you are requesting the Sender URL?

Answer (score 0):

The error "The envelope is locked by another user or in another application" happens when the senderView is active (see here [How to remove lock created by 'Sender View'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819424/how-to-remove-lock-created-by-sender-view?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and would not allow you to make changes to the envelope. So if you added 1 document, created senderView and opened it and then try to use API to add another while view is active - you cannot do it since envelope is locked. Must make sure to do that first.