# How to remove lock created by 'Sender View'?

Tags: docusignapi

In my application, I've created a dashboard for envelopes with a form where users can edit basic envelope recipient information, and the action of the form captures the changes and makes a [PUT request](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm) to update the info on DocuSign. Also on this dashboard is the [Sender View,](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm) which is loaded in the background and made visible when a user clicks on a Bootstrap `nav-tab`.

Upon saving the changes to a recipient via the form, I'm greeted by an error:

```
"errorCode": "EDIT_LOCK_NOT_LOCK_OWNER",\\r\\n  "message": "The user is not the owner of the lock. The envelope is locked by another user or in another application"\\r\\n}'
```

I believe this is due to the Sender View being loaded in the background, thereby preventing changes to the envelope without first clicking "Discard Changes" in the Sender View iFrame. Unfortunately, I cannot rely on my users to do this every time they want to make a change to the envelope. Even if I don't load the Sender View iFrame until it is actually needed, I still don't trust users to discard changes before submitting my form.

I've tried [deleting the lock,](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Envelope%20or%20Template%20Lock.htm) but this proves unsuccessful and I must wait for the lock to timeout before I can even use the Sender View again.

Does the API provide any solution to either forcefully remove the lock on the envelope or duplicate the Sender View's "Discard Changes" action?

Comment: Why are you providing the sender view? For your users to view the envelope and its documents or for them to modify it before sending it? Or something else?

Comment: For users to modify envelopes, specifically adding documents, adding signers, and modifying tabs.

Comment: Based on Ricky S's answer, it looks like there's not much I can do to subvert this. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Sender View locks can unfortunately not be deleted. Locks can only be deleted with the token, which is granted by the lockedByApp (as opposed to lockedByUser). With Sender View, either the Classic DocuSign Experience (CDE) or New DocuSign Experience (NDSE) is the lockedByApp and the GET does not include the token.

Sender View:

```
{
  "lockedByUser": {
    "userName": "Rickey S",
    "userId": "xxxxxxxx-2c1d-493a-89d7-6bb3117b52bf",
    "uri": "/users/xxxxxxxx-2c1d-493a-89d7-6bb3117b52bf"
  },
  "lockedByApp": "New DocuSign Experience",
  "lockedUntilDateTime": "2016-06-15T05:34:16.8600000Z",
  "lockType": "edit"
}
```

API Generated Lock:

```
{
  "lockedByUser": {
    "userName": "Rickey S",
    "userId": "xxxxxxxx-2c1d-493a-89d7-6bb3117b52bf",
    "uri": "/users/xxxxxxxx-2c1d-493a-89d7-6bb3117b52bf"
  },
  "lockedByApp": "Rickey Postman",
  "lockedUntilDateTime": "2016-06-15T05:33:30.6270000Z",
  "lockDurationInSeconds": "120",
  "lockType": "edit",
  "useScratchPad": "false",
  "lockToken": "xxxxxxxxxxAtZmQ4NS00YzNjLTllN2ItZjExMzE3MzliODgy"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
    var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
    try
    {
       // this line will throw error if envelope is not locked, so handle it using try & catch block
       LockInformation lockInfo = envelopesApi.GetLock(accountId, envelopeId);

       // check if this app locked it
        if (lockInfo?.LockDurationInSeconds?.Length > 0)
       {
           // add a header with the LockToken to ensure this app has the right to unlock 
            string LockHeader = $"{{\"lockToken\":\"{lockInfo.LockToken}\"}}";
            envelopesApi.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Edit", LockHeader);
            envelopesApi.DeleteLock(accountId, envelopeId);
       }
    }
    catch (ApiException exp)
    {      
       // Do Whatever you want to do
       
    }
```

I have found this from [How to Unlock Docusign Envelope](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes)