# Sender View Generated Lock

Tags: docusignapi

We have the following scenario:
1. User first accesses the envelope through the Sender View generated from the API.
2. User accesses the envelope through the Sender View again within a short period of time.

We receive the following error: EDIT_LOCK_NOT_LOCK_OWNER

Is there any way we can release this lock through the API?

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing "*lockedByApp*", I believe you'll need to wait for the lock to expire (**lockedUntilDateTime**) -- the lock cannot be Deleted.

For more detailed information, see the answer here: [How to remove lock created by 'Sender View'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819424/how-to-remove-lock-created-by-sender-view)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/delete/

You can DELETE the lock, but you will need the X-Docusign-Edit header with the LockToken (from a GET on the envelope lock).

Comment: I am debugging the lock token generated from the Sender View API and the lock token appears to be null.

Comment: LockedByApp: "Classic DocuSign Experience"